# On the android Incredible, is there any way to make a shortcut to the "All Photos" view?

Tags: gallery, photos, home-screen-shortcuts, htc-droid-incredible, app-widgets

The HTC photo-album takes up an entire screen; is there a way to make a shortcut, or is there a smaller widget or app, that would open up the all-photos view?

The easiest method I've found is to go in via a camera, view the albums, and select "All photos"

Surely there must be a better way?

I'm on the HTC Incredible running Froyo (2.2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have an app called Gallery? I have it in my list. I would say just drag that on your homescreen and you should be good to go.

Comment: that's...... I'm speechless. That should have been obvious. But I kept looking for something called "album" or "photos" or making a shortcut. HAH! Thanks!

Comment: No worries man. Glad it worked for you!

Comment: This should probably be marked as the correct answer then, right?