# Why is Android claiming I have multiple Flickr accounts, and not allowing me to upload to Flickr?

Tags: gallery, share-menu, flickr

Starting about a week ago, my phone -- rooted HTC Incredible, 2.2 -- stopped being able to upload to Flickr. I can't associate any system/device changes with the problem; I rooted a couple of months ago, and updated happily, since then.

I'm not using any special Flickr apps -- just the default "Share >> Flickr" accessed via the [Gallery.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/960/on-the-android-incredible-is-there-any-way-to-make-a-shortcut-to-the-all-photos)

But when I do, I first get prompted to log in to Flickr, then told that I have multiple accounts (I don't) which is not supported.

hunh?

[image: android prompts to sign in to flickr]

[image: android tells me that multiple accounts are not supported]

N.B.: Question may be rephrased over time....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to:

```
Settings -> Accounts and sync
```

Do you see a Flickr account there?  If so, either make sure you are using that account with the Gallery or try deleting that account and trying the Gallery again.

Comment: Only one account was listed. I don't know what was wrong, but I deleted the account, re-created it, and gallery was then happy. Bizarre

Comment: Good to hear :)

Comment: Found this by Googling. I had the exact same problem on an unrooted phone. Strange!

Thanks for the solution. I spotted that account and should have tried this first as well. Guess something updates and broke a link somewhere.